# How to create a new column that follows a particular pattern?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, data-wrangling

I have a data frame df that contains nutrition values. I have to create a new column diabetic wherein there should be yes for the first two rows and no in the third row.

```
df <- data.frame(nutrition = c(199,200,350,175,226,400))
```

Expected output is as follows:-

```
# expect output
diabetic = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recycling technique to assign new column.

```
df$diabetic <- c('Yes', 'Yes', 'No')

df
#  nutrition diabetic
#1       199      Yes
#2       200      Yes
#3       350       No
#4       175      Yes
#5       226      Yes
#6       400       No
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rep` to replicate a vector of values by specifying the `length.out` as the number of rows of the dataset and it will do the replication of those vector

```
df$diabetic <- rep(c("Yes", "Yes", "No"), length.out = nrow(df))
```

---

Or using recycling

```
df  <- transform(df, diabetic = c("Yes", "Yes", "No"))
df
#   nutrition diabetic
#1       199      Yes
#2       200      Yes
#3       350       No
#4       175      Yes
#5       226      Yes
#6       400       No
```

---

Or another option is with `seq` after creating a column "Yes" and then insert the "No" at specific locations

```
df$diabetic <- "Yes"
df$diabetic[seq(3, nrow(df), by = 3)] <- "No"
```

---

Or using `%%` with `ifelse`

```
ifelse(seq_len(nrow(df)) %% 3 == 0, "No", "Yes")
#[1] "Yes" "Yes" "No"  "Yes" "Yes" "No"
```